# Extracting Nupkg files using command line

Tags: nuget

Firstly, I do not want to use Visual Studio at all when dealing with the certain .nupkg files.

I know there is a tool called NuGet Package Explorer and this can export nupkg files to a certain file location using a gui, but I'm looking to setup a MSBuild task to run and unpack about 50 .nupkg files, using the command line.

My question is, is there a tool you can use via the command line which will unpack .nupkg files to a specified file location?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can also use the NuGet command line, by specifying a local host as part of an install. For example if your package is stored in the current directory

```
nuget install MyPackage -Source %cd% -OutputDirectory packages
```

will unpack it into the target directory.

Comment: Just a note that MyPackage is actually a Package ID that is specified in the .nuspec file and not a file name.

Comment: and you have to execute it from console with admin privileges

Comment: Fwiw, in powershell the command looks like:
nuget install MyPackage -Source $pwd -OutputDirectory packages

Comment: I guess %cd% is referring to the current directory. How can I refer to different path in my local system? it does not work when I use a path. "./example/path/"

Comment: I used the absolute path to the file directory to get the -Source to work for me. I didn't include the package name.

Comment: @Rod I am using docker file and need the utilize my .nupkg file and running the below command but linux container doesn't find Install command . What should I do?

RUN Install-Package BuildingBlock.Messaging.Publisher -Source "." "ProductService.Catalog/"

Comment: I had trouble installing my package because the .nupkg file name did not line up with what was specified in the .nuspec. After renaming the .nupkg to include the version i was able to install it locally: NuGet.exe install <packageName> -PreRelease -Source "Directory\To\.nupkg" -Version <full version> -NoCache -DirectDownload -OutputDirectory D:\temp, where the .nupkg physical file name was <Nuget Id>.<Version>.nupkg

Answer (score 185):

NuPKG files are just zip files, so anything that can process a zip file should be able to process a nupkg file, i.e, 7zip.

Comment: There is a proviso with this, which is that NuGet seems to do some sort of encoding of filenames. So, if you use a zip tool, a file you orginally named "A+B.txt" for example will be extracted as "A%2B.txt". This is avoided by using nuget install (as per Andy's answer)

Comment: the file encoding issue was fixed in 4.7.0+

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9459 Links to some side effects of not encoding the filenames, but also links in the comments to the original issues where it was changed, for reference. Note: The are compatibility issues with Nuget 2.x

Answer (score 41):

Rename it to **.zip**, then extract it.

Comment: This is an extremely old question, and if you just change it to a zip that will not answer the question, if you use a zip tool, a file you originally named "A+B.txt" for example will be extracted as "A%2B.txt" - You also don't need to rename it to zip.

Answer (score 5):

**did the same thing like this:**

```
clear
cd PACKAGE_DIRECTORY

function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
    }
}

Dir *.nupkg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace ".nupkg",".zip"  }

Expand-ZIPFile "Package.1.0.0.zip" “DESTINATION_PATH”
```

Comment: Dosent this suffer from the same problem as Oli Wennell mention above? i.e. "A+B.txt" for example will be extracted as "A%2B.txt"?

Answer (score 4):

With PowerShell 5.1 (PackageManagement module)

```
Install-Package -Name MyPackage -Source (Get-Location).Path -Destination C:\outputdirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Rename-Item -Path A_Package.nupkg -NewName A_Package.zip

Expand-Archive -Path A_Package.zip -DestinationPath C:\Reference
```

Comment: At least in PS 7.1.2 you can can use Expand-Archive without changing the file extension on MacOS.

Comment: @Phatmandrake +1 you are correct and this should be an answer, I just verified myself on Big Sur + PS 7.1.3

Comment: This break folder names e.g.  Test Folder will be extracted as Test%20Folder. There will also be extra files in the extracted folder e.g _rels

Answer (score 0):

Just do `unzip package-name.nupkg -d OutputDir`