# Use ValueTuple in Ninja Trader 8 C# .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, trading, valuetuple

This question is beyond the scope of NinjaTrader Customer Service. The trading platform targets .Net 4.5 and I would like to use ValueTuple (.Net 4.7) with it.

I see there is this Nuget Package to add ValueTuple to previous versions of .Net.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/

However Ninja Trader 8 can only Add .Dll files and that is a Nuget Package .nupkg.

Is that possible to extract these DLL from the Nuget Package and Add them to Ninja Trader 8 or is there any other possibility to include this ValueTuple Technology to .Net 4.5? I am quite a newbie I would much appreciate a step by step explanation in case it is possible. Thanks!!

Comment: Bear in mind that nuget packages are really just ordinary zip files, but @Moerwald has posted how you can ask nuget to "install" it to a temporary folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple console application via Visual Studio and add the Nuget package. Open file explorer in your solution folder, go to packages-folder, there you'll find the DLLs you need.

Alternatively, you can download and extract the nupgk via e.g. 7z. See this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587291/extracting-nupkg-files-using-command-line) for further information.

Example for extracting:

```
> nuget install system.valuetuple -OutputDirectory C:\temp\system.valuetuple
```

`C:\temp\system.valuetuple` will contain the value tuple dlls.

Comment: What's the problem?